# ODBC Connection Failed #3151 MS Access --> SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc

I have an MS Access application that links to a SQL Server 2008 db for all of its data.  For years, it has worked fine when the SQL Server was on Win2008 Standard 64-bit SP2 and SQL Server 2008 v10.0.4.  I recently moved the back-end SQL db to a newer server (Win2008 R2 Standard 64-bit and SQL v10.50.1600).  After the move, everything on the application worked just fine as expected, no issues.  However, we have a month-end process that generates relatively large reports (300-500 pages) which uncovered an issue that we don't normally see in our day-to-day processing.

My report is based on a pass-through query.  The query runs almost instantaneously and produces 8000 rows.  I can preview the query and quickly navigate to the end of the RS to see the 8000'th row.  No problem.  If I pull up the report that's based on that query, I can see that there are 350 pages and I can navigate page-by-page through the report with no problem.  I can even type in a page number and jump to page 50, 100, 150, etc. with no problem. Note, there is no processing/code/logic happening on any fired events on the report - just displaying and formatting the data.

HERE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM OCCURS:  If I preview the report and try to jump to the last page from the first page, it'll sit and think for a while (38 seconds to be exact) and then throw **Error #3151 ODBC Connection to [DNS Name] Failed.**

If I simply update the connect string on the pass-through query to point it back to the "older" SQL Server and run the same thing, it works just fine.  I've tried adjusting the connect string to use IP address instead of DNS name, no luck.  This is a process that's worked for years with no problem so I know the client-side logic is sound.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Is there anything in the SQL Errorlog? What about the Event Logs? (Server side and Client). When you jump to page 349 and then page down, does it do the same thing?

Comment: Nothing is noted in the SQL Error log nor in the Windows Event logs (server or client). If I try to jump to page 349, I get the error. If I go by 50 records at a time and make it up to 350, I then have free reign to navigate through the entire report with no problems. It acts like it can't make that big jump, but can accept the accumulation of smaller jumps.

Comment: 1 more bit of interesting discovery...when previewing the report, if I type in page 350 (last page) on the navigation button instead of hitting the >| button to goto the last page, it jumps right to it with no problem and I can then go all the way back to the beginning and then >| to the end with no problem.  The reason this is an issue is because we get the error when printing - we can't print the report without getting to page 80 or so and then we get the error.

Comment: When you upgraded to the latest version of SQL Server, did you also upgrade the ODBC drivers on the client workstations? The latest native ODBC client is quite fast with R2 in my experience, and may be required to get the best reliability out of it.

Comment: David - I've confirmed the installation of MDAC 2.8 SP1 on the client workstation.  Not sure if there's anything newer than that.  Thanks.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the MDAC. It's a matter of installing the native SQL Server ODBC client (version 10.something). It's usually party of the download of SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is an entirely shoddy solution and not really safe with multiple people running it on the same DB or Access file... but it might get you running today and give you some breathing room. But remember - Broken gets fixed, shoddy lasts forever.

Take the query from the report, and before you run it, dump the results into an empty temporary table (either on the MS SQL side, or the MS Access side) and then make the report run off of the temporary table instead. Remember to clean it out afterwards so no-one relies on that data for anything.

If it works on the MS Access side, but not on the MS SQL side, then that'll confirm there is  something with the new server's configuration.

Comment: :) Thanks CodeSlave.  I appreciate the suggested workaround.  I've considered drastic measures such as that, but luckily I do have a viable work-around in that this all works if I copy the .mdb to the actual SQL Server itself and run the job directly on the server in a pinch so that's what I'll probably do. But I really need to be able to run from a workstation so my users can do their own work and not have me do it for them on server.  Anyone have any other ideas?

Comment: Actually, I think this is a great suggestion. To prevent bloat, then your code should create a temp accDB, link to that temp table, execute the pass-though query (use the pass-tough as an append query to the temp table). I STRONGLY suggest this approach due to report system tends often re-iterates the data several times and this cases huge drag on the server. This simple approach has reduced reporting generating times from 60 seconds down to 2 seconds.

Comment: Your users will see mind boggling spectacular increase in report performance. On application startup create the temp accDB file (deleting if the old one exists). It is "easy" to create the table, since  you just execute a make table query based on the pass-though. You empty this table and leave it in the front end. Then on app startup you create temp accDB, and "transfers" this blank table to the temp accDB. This means you as the developer never have to "create" or setup the table structure. How to create the temp database can be found here:http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/temptables.htm